# Unable to connect to Redis instance running on Azure Linux VM from Python

Tags: python, azure, redis, redis-py

I created an Ubuntu VM on Azure. In its inbound networking filters, I added ports **22** (for **SSH**ing) and **6379** (for Redis). Following this, I **SSH**ed into an instance from my bash shell, downloaded, built and installed Redis from source. The resultant `redis.conf` file is located in `/tmp/redis-stable`, so I edited that to comment out the `bind 127.0.0.1` rule.

Then I started `redis-server redis.conf` from the `/tmp/redis-stable` directory, and it started normally, following which I **SSH**ed into another instance of the VM, started `redis-cli` and set some keys. Retrieved them, working correctly.

Now in Python I am running this command:

```
r = redis.Redis(host='same_which_I_use_for_SSHing', port=6379, password='pwd')
```

It connects immediately (looks weird). But then when I try a simple command like `r.get("foo")`, I get this error:

```
>>> r.get("foo")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/lib/python3.5/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 484, in connect
    sock = self._connect()
  File "/lib/python3.5/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 511, in _connect
    socket.SOCK_STREAM):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/socket.py", line 732, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/lib/python3.5/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 667, in execute_command
    connection.send_command(*args)
  File "/lib/python3.5/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 610, in send_command
    self.send_packed_command(self.pack_command(*args))
  File "/lib/python3.5/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 585, in send_packed_command
    self.connect()
  File "/lib/python3.5/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 489, in connect
    raise ConnectionError(self._error_message(e))
redis.exceptions.ConnectionError: Error 8 connecting to username@ip_address. nodename nor servname provided, or not known.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/lib/python3.5/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 484, in connect
    sock = self._connect()
  File "/lib/python3.5/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 511, in _connect
    socket.SOCK_STREAM):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/socket.py", line 732, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/lib/python3.5/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 976, in get
    return self.execute_command('GET', name)
  File "/lib/python3.5/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 673, in execute_command
    connection.send_command(*args)
  File "/lib/python3.5/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 610, in send_command
    self.send_packed_command(self.pack_command(*args))
  File "/lib/python3.5/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 585, in send_packed_command
    self.connect()
  File "/lib/python3.5/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 489, in connect
    raise ConnectionError(self._error_message(e))
redis.exceptions.ConnectionError: Error 8 connecting to username@ip_address. nodename nor servname provided, or not known.
```

Any idea how to fix this? FYI, the `username@ip_address` in the error message is the same I use for **SSH** from bash and connecting to Redis from Python respectively:

```
ssh username@ip_address
r = redis.Redis(host='username@ip_address', port=6379, password='pwd')
```

I also tried adding `bind 0.0.0.0` in the `redis.conf` file after commenting out the `bind 127.0.0.1` line. Same result.

Update: I tried setting protected mode to no in the config file, followed by running `sudo ufw allow 6379` in the VM. Still same result. But now I get a weird error when I run `redis-server redis.conf`. I don't get the typical redis cube which shows up as a figure Instead I get this:

[image]

After this, if I enter `redis-cli` and issue a simple command like `set foo boo`, I get this error message:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> set foo 1
(error) MISCONF Redis is configured to save RDB snapshots, but it is currently not able to persist on disk. Commands that may modify the data set are disabled, because this instance is configured to report errors during writes if RDB snapshotting fails (stop-writes-on-bgsave-error option). Please check the Redis logs for details about the RDB error.
```

Even shutdown fails after this. I have to run `grep` to find the process if of redis-server and kill it manually, following which `redis-server` command needs to be run to start it normally. But of course, I still cannot connect from remote Mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to create an Ubuntu VM on Azure, build & configure redis server from source code, and add a port rule for my VM NSG on Azure portal, then I connected the redis server via the same code with python redis package successfully.

Here is my steps as below.

1. Create an Ubuntu 18.04 VM on Azure portal.
2. Connect the Ubuntu VM via SSH to install the build packages (include `build-essential`, `gcc` and `make`), download & decompress the `tar.gz` file of redis source code from `redis.io`, and build & test the redis server with `make` & `make test`.
3. Configure the `redis.conf` via `vim`, to change the `bind` configuration from `127.0.0.1` to `0.0.0.0`.
4. Add a new port rule of `6379` port with TCP into the NSG for the `Network Interface` shown in the tab `Settings -> Networking` of my VM on Azure portal, as the figures below.

[image]
Notes: There are two NSG in my `Networking` tab, the second one is related to my `Network Interface` which can be accessed via internet.
[image] 
and 
[image]
5. Install `redis` via `pip install redis` on my local machine.
6. Open a termial to type `python` to try to connect the redis server hosted on my Azure Ubuntu VM and get the value of the `foo` key successfully.

```
>>> import redis
>>> r = redis.Redis(host='xxx.xx.xx.xxx')
>>> r.get('foo')
b'bar'
```

There are two key issues I found within my testing.

1. For `redis.conf`, the binding host must be `0.0.0.0`. If not, redis server will be running in protected mode to refuse the query.
2. For the NSG port rules, make sure the new port rule added in the NSG attached to the current network interface, not the default subnet.
3. The python package `redis` is lazy evaluation, only connect redis server when first command request happened.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Peter. I found that I already had the exact same rule created. For me, the protocol was set to `Any` instead of the more restrictive `TCP`. However, unlike your configuration, mine does not impact any subnet. Any idea how to make it similar to yours? Here is my configuration: https://imgur.com/a/SyxJyzF. Note that your says "Impacts 1 subnet" in one place.

Comment: Wow. In fact it does seem to work! But I can't figure out what I did! When I just changed the protocol to `TCP` from `Any` and tried it again, I first got a different error, that it is running in protected mode, I need to turn that off. As I had mentioned at the end of my answer, I had earlier tried that, and after that, even `redis-cli` was failing locally. However, I did that again, and this time it is working correctly!

Comment: @SexyBeast So now, any issues or any concern?

Comment: One, though unrelated (I will award you the bounty), the connection often dies. For example, I typed `r.get('foo')`, I got 123. If I type the command again after 5 minutes (without having queried Redis in the mean time), this time it takes lot of time to print the value. Once it does, subsequent queries again start returning quickly. And sometimes, it does not even return after long time, it just returns `None`, and I have to `ssh` to my remote VM and refresh the redis server, then refresh the connection in my Python client, and then it starts working again. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: @SexyBeast It seems to be caused by your VM size or VM Family, because Azure may consider for performance balance to make the idle VM sleep which will cause the connection dies. So you can try to upgrade your VM size or keep your VM alive via SSH ping or Redis ping.

Comment: Got it. Thanks!